# starting Xephyr server with auth for some other user

Tags: xauth, xephyr

I have a situation where user0, with access to display :0 on the localhost, needs to run Xephyr :1 such that this Xephyr server is only accessible to user1 clients on the localhost.  Is this configuration possible, and if so, how is it done?

I tried giving user1 an .Xauthority with an MIT magic cookie (via xauth) for :1, and passing that .Xauthority into Xephyr's -auth option, but that does not work.  I can make it work without any security, allowing both users to connect to :1, but I would prefer to prevent user0 from running clients in :1 if possible, as well as prevent user1 from directly running clients in :0.